# how to display Tooltip on click of an image link

Tags: jquery, css, tooltip

I have an icon when clicked I want it to show a tooltip

```
<a class="toolclick"  href="#" ><i class="icon-ellipsis-vertical"></i></a>
```

script

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready( function() {
        $( '.toolclick' ).tooltip( {title: "Hooray!", trigger: "click"} ); 
    } );
</script>
```

The tooltip doesn't show on click of the icon

Comment: Do you want tooltip on hover or click?

Comment: i want it on click

Answer (score 0):

> Html Code:

```
 <div id="tt">Test</div>
```

> jQuery Code:

```
   $('#tt').on({
  "click": function() {
    $(this).tooltip({ items: "#tt", content: "Displaying on click"});
    $(this).tooltip("open");
  },
  "mouseout": function() {      
     $(this).tooltip("disable");   
  }
});
```

Try this.

Comment: i want the tooltip to show on click not on hover

Comment: what is #tt is it the anchor class?

Comment: tt is id, I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

It is batter way to display tool tip when mouse hover on element.

Try below code if you want to display tooltip on hover event.

```
<div class='toolclick'>
    Here you can write your tooltip content
</div>

$('.icon-ellipsis-vertical').hover(function(){
    $('.toolclick').tooltip({title: "Hooray!", trigger: "click"}); 
});
```

For display tooltip onclick.

```
$('.icon-ellipsis-vertical').click(function(){
    $('.toolclick').tooltip({title: "Hooray!", trigger: "click"}); 
});
```