# Creating a tooltip for an image with a click through (html, scss)

Tags: html, css, sass, tooltip

I have a social media icon with a click-through URL. When someone hovers over the icon, I would like a sentence to be displayed over it (a tooltip). I've used a "title" command, and it's doing the job, but I can't style it. So, I guess using an inline span or a span class, would do the job. I've read a few online articles, and tried to mimic those setups, but I just can't get the tooltip to show up. I need someone to show how the html should be (div class/span class) and the scss setup also.

This is my code without the tooltip, and this is where i want to implement it

```
<div class="socials">
<a href="https://twitter.com/user" target="_blank">
<img src="../images/twitter.png"  alt="twitter logo" >
</a>
```

Note: I am only 4 weeks old in coding. So, I am looking for something that is easy to understand and troubleshoot.

The html/css setup seen in these websites is what I had used but couldn't get it to work:

1. [How to add tooltip to image on hover with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921421/how-to-add-tooltip-to-image-on-hover-with-css)
2. [how to display Tooltip on click of an image link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58315570/how-to-display-tooltip-on-click-of-an-image-link)
3. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp

The tooltip seen on this site has the closest tooltip i am looking for:
4. http://theorniphile.info/creating-tooltips-for-images-with-css/index.html

Most of them don't have an example where an image is a click through.

Looking forward to hearing from you, and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use a pseudo-element and position it

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

a {
  position: relative;
}

a:after {
  content: "this is a tooltip";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(-120%);
  padding: 0 .25em;
  background: lightblue;
  width: fit-content;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: none;
}

a:hover:after {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://twitter.com/user" target="_blank">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/50/50" alt="twitter logo">
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Paulie, I shall give this a try tomorrow and see how it goes!